# zend modules like in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, zend-framework, zend-framework-modules

is there a way to do modules in rails 3 like zend framework modules ? In zend framework, you have a folder 'modules' like following structure:

```
/application/modules/admin
/application/modules/site
/application/modules/service
```

and it's routed in this way:

```
http://myapp.local/admin
http://myapp.local/service
http://myapp.local/ -- to site module (default).
```

How can I achieve this in Rails 3? There's a better way to do this type things in rails ?

Thanks in advANCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about *controller namespaces*?

```
                          # URL:
resources :projects       # /projects
resources :people         # /people

namespace "admin" do      # /admin
  resources :projects     # /admin/projects
  resources :people       # /admin/people
end

namespace "service" do    # /service
  resources :what         # /service/what
  resources :ever         # /service/ever
end
```

Controller paths:

```
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
app/controllers/people_controller.rb
app/controllers/admin/projects_controller.rb
app/controllers/admin/people_controller.rb
app/controllers/service/what_controller.rb
app/controllers/service/ever_controller.rb
```

More information here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Answer (score 0):

This is sounding a little like Models and Routes for Rails 3. I wouldn't say you need a specific model for Admin, that would be an extension of the User model.

The [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) might put some of this in perspective.