# Using resources with custom controller names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm using nested resources, however i come across controller names that should be more descriptive.

For instance i have a controller `ProductsController` and `ImagesController`

```
resources :products do
  resources :images
end
```

This works fine, but later i might need to use the `ImageController` for other than products images, therefore it should be named **ProductsImagesController**.

But how can i specify the controller name on `resources()` without falling back to something ugly like:

```
match 'products/images' => 'products_images#index'
match 'products/images/new' => 'products_images#new'
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
resources :products do
  resources :images, :controller => "products_images"
end
```

Comment: I am having an issue with this in rails 4? 

resources :analytics, :controller=> '/admin/portal/api/analytics' do
  collection do
    get :products_by_user_id
    get :products_by_stylist
  end


end

Answer (score 2):

Coming from a Zend Framework background, I think you are looking for a modular structure. Rails seems to offer this, called 'namespacing':

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

That creates routes to Admin::PostsController and Admin::CommentsController. In your case, you would have Products::ImagesController.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

I found out from this other accepted answer: [zend modules like in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264583/zend-modules-like-in-rails)