# Renaming controller on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just created a new rails app but I want to change the name of the controller from weathers.rb to forecasts.rb because weathers just sounds odd. Can someone advise how I can change it via the terminal. I can just delete the file and start again since I literally just started but would love to know if its possible to make the change on the terminal and if so, how to do it.

Comment: I believe you can do what you are trying to achieve by indicating your custom controller name in the routes file. Check the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553870/using-resources-with-custom-controller-names

Comment: In the terminal you need to access the file and rewrite it. To rename a controller you need to rename the filename as well as the class name. Also the routes...This can be done by terminal but might be easier in texteditor. to completely destroy and make a new controller use the rails comands described below.

Answer (score 0):

Your just going to have to go about renaming the `controller`, `model` and `routes` accordingly.

Or you can delete the controller, model like so:

```
rails d controller lalala
rails d model yadayada
```

Or if you generated this controller via a scaffold then you can delete it like this and regenerate it.

```
 rails d scaffold hohoho
```

If you don't want to take route, then you might have to rename the files